# 7-ZIP relative path for files

Tags: 7-zip

I have to create an archive with multiples files place in subdirectories.
for example:

- .../documents/offers/001.pdf
- .../documents/offers/002.pdf
- .../documents/drawings/001.dwg
- .../documents/drawings/002.dwg

I would like to add the files 001.pdf & 001.dwg keeping the directory structure from the directory where the 7za.exe file is stored.

The files will be added using the absolute path (using a database to archive some files)

I have checked the switches available but I don't find any that discribe what i want to do

Add a directory is working, but I don't want all the files, juste a few of them.

Comment: Is this on windows or linux?

Answer (score 0):

The following uses the Windows command "forfiles" along with 7zip.  It grabs all files under the directory C:\yourPath (/s = recursive) where the date is equal to or greater than a given date (/d 01/18/2018).  The /m *.* parameter says to only look at files, not directories, in regard to the cutoff date.  The -spf param tells 7zip you want the full qualified path. (-spf is available in at least ver. 15 of 7zip).  "@path" is a parameter used by forfiles for each file found that meets the criteria.

forfiles /s /m *.* /p C:\yourPath /c "cmd /c 7z a -spf -t7z c:\yourArchive.7z @path" /d 01/18/2018